# Remove items from collection in VBA

Tags: vba

I want to remove collA(1)(9, 0), collA(1)(9, 1), collA(1)(9, 2), collA(1)(9, 3), collA(1)(9, 4), collA(1)(9, 5) and collA(1)(9, 6).

The remove statement in the Sub Test() below doesn't work.

How can this problem be solved?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim A() As Integer
    Redim A(0 To 367907, 0 To  6) As Integer

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 0 To 367907
    For j = 0 To 6    
        A(i, j) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, j + 1)
    Next j
    Next i

    Dim collA As VBA.Collection

    Set collA = New Collection
    collA.Add A

    Erase A

    collA(1).Remove 10     '<--- This doesn't work

End Sub
```

Comment: Your collection only has one item, a range object. The range object doesn't have a remove property

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need the array, you can add the values directly to the collection object. That's what its for :)

If you want then remove cell `D2` from the collection you have to know it's index

So set up your sheet like this

[image]

then notice

your collection starts with number 1 and the first item added is cell `A1`, then second cell `B1`

therefore your index 10 is cell `D2`

use the below code to remove D2 from the collection

```
Sub Test()

    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 1 To 6
            c.Add Cells(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = 1 To c.Count
        Debug.Print c.Item(i), "count: " & i, "total items: " & c.Count
    Next i

    c.Remove 10
    Debug.Print vbCrLf

    For i = 1 To c.Count
        Debug.Print c.Item(i), "count: " & i, "total items: " & c.Count
    Next i

End Sub
```

results in Immediate Window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

[image]

Comment: @user2042719 sorry but you are misunderstanding the concept.

Comment: As I said: "I want to remove collA(1)(9, 0), collA(1)(9, 1), collA(1)(9, 2), collA(1)(9, 3), collA(1)(9, 4), collA(1)(9, 5) and collA(1)(9, 6).". Those correspond to A(9, 0), A(9, 1), A(9, 2), A(9, 3), A(9, 4), A(9, 5) and A(9, 6). I want to remove those with ONE statement. Isn't it possible to add arrays to a Collection, so that each item in the Collection contains an Array?